# how to forward to another controller method with same URI?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, forward

I have 2 following methods in my controler with same URI:

```
         @RequestMapping(value = "/member/createCompany/addParams", method =  RequestMethod.POST)
         public String setCompanyParams(
             @ModelAttribute @Valid CampaignBeanDto campaignBeanDto, BindingResult bindingResult,
             @RequestParam(value = "g-recaptcha-response") String  recapchaResponse,
             HttpSession session, Principal principal, Model model) throws Exception {
                  return "forward:/member/createCompany/addParams";
         }

         @RequestMapping(value = "/member/createCompany/addParams", method = RequestMethod.GET)
         public String createCompanyAddParams(Principal principal, Model model, HttpSession session) {        
               return "member/createCompany/addParams";
         }
```

I invoke get POST method from frontend and it loops and invokes POST method again.

how to rewrite forward to invoke GET method?

Comment: Use `redirect:` instead of `forward:`

Comment: I am afraid that I will lose model attributes

Comment: Call `createCompanyAddParams()` from `setCompanyParams()` then?

Comment: Yes - it is works. Is it impossble if I want use "forward" ?